# sending json object to function python

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, object

I need to pass a JSON object to a separate function in python

```
import json

userList = [{username: 'userName', email: 'email'}]

listString = json.dumps(userList)
print(json.loads(listString))
```

this will print the same object: `[{username: 'userName', email: 'email'}]`

I know it isn't possible to pass a JSON object directly to another function which is why I'm turning it into a string and trying to unpack it in the new function

```
testFunction(listString)

def testFunction(oldList):
    print(json.dumps(oldList))
```

this will print out `[{'username': 'userName', 'email': 'email'}]` but won't let me return the object from the new function. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
def testFunction(oldList):
    newList = json.loads(oldList)
    # code to append to newList

    return newList


Response: null
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the dictionary that you get from `json.loads()`?

Comment: After I'm done appending to the dictionary, I try to return the whole thing but only get null. Sorry I made a typo in my question, I edited it.

Comment: Your assertion that "it isn't possible to pass a JSON object directly to another function" is *completely false*. Python does not restrict you passing any type of object between functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a homework question - you should make that clear in your question.

> I know it isn't possible to pass a JSON object directly to another function

There is no "JSON object" you have a python list that contains a python dictionary. json.dumps turns that list into a JSON string and json.loads(string) takes that string and returns a python list.

You can pass your userList to the function.  Or if this is homework and you are required to pass a JSON string you use json.dumps to convert your list to a JSON string first:

```
import json

userList = [{"username": 'userName', "email": 'email'}]

listString = json.dumps(userList)

def foo(jsonstring):
  lst = json.loads(jsonstring)
  lst[0]["username"] = "Alex"
  return lst

newList = foo(listString)

print(newList)
```

The output is:

```
[{'username': 'Alex', 'email': 'email'}]
```

After your edit I see the problem in your code.  Do you see what you did?