# (pymongo) passing Json as return function input

Tags: python, json, pymongo

I just know we cannot directly pass json to function
that I learn from [sending json object to function python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621477/sending-json-object-to-function-python)

so that I used `json.dumps()`  transform into str when input in function, and return back to json format by `json.loads()`

but there still cannot run properly, what is the reason, and is there any simple way?

**python code (pymongo):**

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/users")

def Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json_inStr_list):
    
    mydb_Name= input_new_DB_name

    mydb = myclient[mydb_Name]

    existing_DB = myclient.list_database_names()

    dblist = myclient.list_database_names()
    if mydb_Name in dblist:
      boolean_db_exist = True

    mycol = mydb["input_new_collection_name"]

    existing_collection = mydb.list_collection_names()

    collist = mydb.list_collection_names()
    if "input_new_collection_name" in collist:
      boolean_collection_exist = True

    json_input_end = json.loads(input_json_inStr_list)
    x = mycol.insert_many(json_input_end)

    Inserted_data = x.inserted_ids

    return existing_DB, existing_collection, Inserted_data


input_new_DB_name = input("Enter ur new DB name: ")
input_new_collection_name = input("Enter ur new collection name: ")
input_json = input("Enter the json input: ")
input_json_inStr_list = json.dumps(input_json)


list_of_DB ,list_of_collection, new_insert_data = Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json)

print(list_of_DB)
print(list_of_collection)
print(new_insert_data)
```

**my input:**

> Enter ur new DB name: 111112333
> Enter ur new collection name: wwfsvdf
> Enter the json input: [{"name": "Joy", "ID": "000111", "Age": 23 ,
> "time" : json_datetime},{ "name": "Tom", "ID": "000222", "Age": 88,
> "time" : json_datetime} ]

```
Enter ur new DB name: 111112333
Enter ur new collection name: wwfsvdf
Enter the json input: [{"name": "Joy", "ID": "000111", "Age": 23 , "time" : json_datetime},{ "name": "Tom", "ID": "000222", "Age": 88, "time" : json_datetime} ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB\insert_collection.py", line 51, in <module>
    list_of_DB ,list_of_collection, new_insert_data = Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB\insert_collection.py", line 36, in Create_DB_save_data
    json_input_end = json.loads(input_json_inStr_list)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 55 (char 54)
```

I just tried again with input Json format list

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/users")

def Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json):
    
    mydb_Name= input_new_DB_name

    mydb = myclient[mydb_Name]

    existing_DB = myclient.list_database_names()

    dblist = myclient.list_database_names()
    if mydb_Name in dblist:
      boolean_db_exist = True

    mycol = mydb["input_new_collection_name"]

    existing_collection = mydb.list_collection_names()

    collist = mydb.list_collection_names()
    if "input_new_collection_name" in collist:
      boolean_collection_exist = True

    My_list = []
    My_list.append(input_json) 
    x = mycol.insert_many(My_list)

    Inserted_data = x.inserted_ids

    return existing_DB, existing_collection, Inserted_data


input_new_DB_name = input("Enter ur new DB name: ")
input_new_collection_name = input("Enter ur new collection name: ")
input_json = input("Enter the json input: ")


list_of_DB ,list_of_collection, new_insert_data = Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json)

print(list_of_DB)
print(list_of_collection)
print(new_insert_data)
```

output still getting error though(I know it should work, so maybe somewhere is wrong):

```
Enter ur new DB name: (practice_10_14)-0002
Enter ur new collection name: (practice_10_14)_customer_data
Enter the json input: [{"name": "Joy", "ID": "000111", "Age": 23 , "time" : json_datetime},{ "name": "Tom", "ID": "000222", "Age": 88, "time" : json_datetime} ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB\insert_collection.py", line 42, in <module>
    list_of_DB ,list_of_collection, new_insert_data = Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB\insert_collection.py", line 30, in Create_DB_save_data
    x = mycol.insert_many(My_list)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 706, in insert_many
    blk.ops = [doc for doc in gen()]
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 706, in <listcomp>
    blk.ops = [doc for doc in gen()]
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 697, in gen
    common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\common.py", line 521, in validate_is_document_type
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

The `TypeError: document must be an instance of dict ...` made me thought I need transfer to string(but no need)

Comment: Of course you **can** pass references to JSON whether it be in its string form or after converting to a Python dictionary. Please re-read the stack**overflow** question that you allude to where it's made very clear that the assertion in that question is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the return function can pass Jason as input, this is correct
I was stock on line42 that `input_json_str = input("Enter the json input: ")` the `input(" ")` will defult take what ever data as string

and I transfer by `json.loads()` as Json data input intp function

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/users")

def Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json):
    
    mydb_Name= input_new_DB_name

    mydb = myclient[mydb_Name]

    existing_DB = myclient.list_database_names()

    dblist = myclient.list_database_names()
    if mydb_Name in dblist:
      boolean_db_exist = True

    mycol = mydb["input_new_collection_name"]

    existing_collection = mydb.list_collection_names()

    collist = mydb.list_collection_names()
    if "input_new_collection_name" in collist:
      boolean_collection_exist = True

    My_list = []
    My_list.append(input_json) 
    x = mycol.insert_many(My_list)

    Inserted_data = x.inserted_ids

    return existing_DB, existing_collection, Inserted_data


input_new_DB_name = input("Enter ur new DB name: ")
input_new_collection_name = input("Enter ur new collection name: ")
input_json_str = input("Enter the json input: ")
input_json =json.loads(input_json_str)

list_of_DB ,list_of_collection, new_insert_data = Create_DB_save_data(input_new_DB_name, input_new_collection_name, input_json)

print(list_of_DB)
print(list_of_collection)
print(new_insert_data)
```

output:

```
C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.13_connect_mongoDB>python insert_collection.py
Enter ur new DB name: (practice_10_14)-0004444
Enter ur new collection name: (practice_10_14)_customer_dataffffff
Enter the json input: {"name222222":"joy22222","age":22}
['(practice_10_14)', '(practice_10_14)-0001', '(practice_10_14)-0002', 'admin', 'cloud_db', 'cloud_db_back', 'config', 'gz_test', 'local']
[]
[ObjectId('634921b57c8cbbe1dd2d1e97')]
```